# Change order status in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, order-status

I am using *`sales_order_save_after`* event.
In observer method, I have written following code:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
```

But after order placed, order state is displaying as "processing" only. I have checked that observer method is called.

Answer (score 1):

*`sales_order_save_after`* is called several times whenever save() *`function`* of model `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.

As you want to ***change order status to new*** whenever order place means order is just place.

If put a condition like  *`if(!$order->getId())`* at observer then it will only fire when order is placed.Because *getId()* give null until order save

> ```
> $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
> if(!$order->getId()):
> $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
> endif;
> ```

Comment: should I write $order->save(); ?

Comment: no.. not need ..

Comment: Ok. let me check it.

Comment: But when I am printing $order->getid() then it is printing a order id. I am also getting order increment id.

Comment: Without $order->save() order status is not changing and when I write $order->save() then that line is not excuting.

Comment: How to get exact  shipping_state using observer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to Change order status in the observer file,

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if(!$order->getId()):
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
    $order->setId($order->getId());
    $order->save();
endif;
```

Or You can use below code also,

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if(!$order->getId()):
    $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    $orderModel->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
    $orderModel->setId($order->getId());
    $orderModel->save();
endif;
```